# Should I hold ADA as company to pay fees and issue Native Tokens for my game?

Tags: smart-contract, native-assets

As far I know Carano will allow to pay fees in Native Tokens, so fees will be on ADA + a reward. But I have questions about it after reading [this blog post](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/02/25/babel-fees/) from IOHK.

If I'm running the economy of my game, for instance as premium currency Gems with ticker GEMS let's have in mind these transactions:
t1. Player buys GEMS in-game, so will pay 1.45$ for 1$ worth GEMS + Apple/Google commissions + blockchain fees.

- Q1. Either including an external payment system or validating Apple/Google transaction, Where is coming the liquidity? Me, as Company, should I hold a bag of ADA to pay fees and issue the equivalent in GEMS?
- Q2. How a staking pool decide to accept which Native Tokens?
- Q3. Is the staking pool nodes getting ADA + GEMS with every transaction?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "pay fees in Native Tokens"? Are you referring to the transaction fees?

Comment: Yes, not sure if I understand it properly, you pay transaction fees in ADA and... you also send your native token to the pool?

Comment: Stake-pools don't do anything with native tokens. Everything a stake-pool does is done with ADA. ADA is delegated to the pool and rewards are paid in ADA. It's not possible to delegate native tokens to a stake-pool.

Comment: alright! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post is (to my understanding) just a thought experiment. I haven't heard of any plans for Cardano to support something like the "Babel fees" described in the blog post.

- Q1: In order to send some native tokens to another wallet, you need to have your own wallet with the native tokens and some ADA to cover transaction fees. There is a minimum amount of ADA that needs to be sent together with any native tokens (currently ~1.4 ADA). This amount will be transferred to the wallet of the player who buys your GEMS. Then you also have to cover the transaction fee of ~0.17 ADA.
- Q2: There is no such feature in stake-pools as of now and to my best knowledge it is not planned to have such a feature. There are projects that do something called an ISO (initial stake pool offering). A company creates a stake-pool and takes all rewards as fees. Then they send some of their native tokens (e.g. GEMS) to the people who delegated their ADA to the pool. But this is not what you want I think.
- Q3: No, stake-pools only receive rewards in ADA.